# Javalite framwork in production env

Tags: embedded-jetty, javalite, activeweb

I am going to ship out the first version of webapp base on Javalite framework. Thanks the framework, it makes the developing rapidly :). Here are some goals in my production env.

1. I would like to use `maven-assembly-plugin` to assemble all dependencies into one jar, named like `myapp-with-dependencies.jar`
2. I'd like to run the webapp using command line: `java -jar myapp-with-dependencies.jar`, so that I can create daemon service for `myapp`

I've checked all sample apps of Javalite repo on github, Below lists the entry `Main.java` in development env

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext("src/main/webapp", "/"); // <- should package as war in production?
    webapp.addAliasCheck(new AllowSymLinkAliasChecker());
    server.setHandler(webapp);
    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join();
  }
}
```

`new WebAppContext("src/main/webapp", "/");` only works on development mode? and how to change it to production mode?

The question may be related to embedded-jetty. If you have any experiences on shipping Javalite on production env, could you like to share it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you found is a very simple way to run Jetty embedded. The other question you asked is about ActiveWeb projects running in a different environment.

Please, see http://javalite.io/app-config. We always use AppConfig to load properties from property files that correspond to a current environment. That page contains all the information you need to setup your system for different environments

**Step 1:**

```
/app_config
        |
        +--global.properties
        |
        +--development.properties
        |
        +--staging.properties
        |
        +--production.properties
```

**Step 2**

Add properties to your property file, for instance `development.properties`:

```
first.name=John
phrase= And the name is ${first.name}
```

**Step 3**

Pull properties with a `p()` method:

```
import static org.javalite.app_config.AppConfig.p;
...
System.out.println(p("phrase"));
```

When you run locally, it will be reading the `development.properties` file by default.

If you set an environment variable `ACTIVE_ENV=production`, then you code will be reading from the `production.properties` file.

**How we run JavaLite apps in  production environment.**

Generally, we develop using a Jetty Maven plugin - there are many examples of that: https://github.com/javalite

Our standard Maven build creates a WAR file that includes all dependencies as jar files under WEB_INF/lib - that is, we do not create a jar with dependencies. 
Once we have that WAR file, we deploy it on a standard production container, like any other Java app (JBoss, Tomcat, etc.).

Comment: Thanks mention AppConfig toolkits. I've migrated my `application.properties` into javalite manner. Looks so great! 

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are asking 2 different things.

Do you want a self executing jar with everything you need in it?
If so, then you would use a `ServletContextHandler` not a WAR or `WebAppContext`.

See:

- [maven jetty embedded (fat jar) - src/main/webapp missing in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433158/775715)
- [How to get embedded Jetty serving html files from a Jar, not a War](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33836614/775715)

And example project at

- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-uber-jar

If you want to use `WebAppContext` and have it be self executing, then you'll basically have what's known as a "Live War".

The basics are that you will have multiple maven (or gradle) projects that manage the different layers you will need to pull off this kind of live-war setup.

See:

- [Embedded Jetty with exploded war, using annotated config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37553587/775715)
- [Error while executing WAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40251997/775715)

And example project at

- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war